# What is origin of "Rank" in Higher-Rank Polymorphism?

Tags: haskell, purescript

I'm looking for a similar explanation to higher-kind polymorphism, where a kind is simply a predicated set of types.

Answer (score 6):

The rank of a type describes the depth at which universal quantifiers appear contravariantly (Kfoury & Tiuryn, 1992):

```
Monotypes τ, σ(0) ::= a | τ1 → τ2
Polytypes σ(n+1) ::= σ n | σ n → σ(n+1) | ∀a.σ(n+1)
```

Here are some examples:

```
Int → Int Rank 0
∀a.a → a Rank 1
Int → (∀a.a → a) Rank 1
(∀a.a → a) → Int Rank 2
```

https://functionalprogramming.slack.com/archives/C0432GV99/p1509647117000276